# How long does it take for Mt Gox withdrawal to Dwolla?

Tags: mtgox, sell-bitcoins, withdrawal, dwolla

I just sold some BTC and transferred money from Mt Gox to Dwolla.  My Mt. Gox account had $150 in it, and now both accounts are zero.

- Is it normal for neither account to reflect the new balance after an account transfer?
- How long does an account transfer take?

I've taken the matter up with Mt Gox support, but since they are in Japan, I'm not sure when they will get back to me.  I'd appreciate any anecdotal or historical interaction you've had with this type of exchange.

Answer (score 1):

When I've used Mt. Gox, it's taken anywhere from two to seven days for the Dwolla payment to hit my account.